# Median regression comparing continuous variables between three groups, adjusting for demographic variables

Tags: regression, quantile-regression

I would like to compare whether 4 continuous variables have a difference among 3 groups (disease states A, B, C). There are 48 cases in the sample, however, the continuous variables are quite skewed. I have run Kruskal-Wallis with post-hoc Dunn's tests for pairwise comparisons. I would like to however run another analysis while adjusting for age, sex, and post-mortem delay (continuous variable). I have gone ahead and used separate median regressions for this, each time using one of the 4 continuous variables as the dependent variable, and adding disease state, age, sex, and post-mortem delay as predictors. This is working fine, except I'm getting p-values in reference to one of the disease state groups and therefore missing the comparison between the other two groups (i.e. am only getting A-C and B-C, and not A-B). I am wondering two things:

1. Is this an acceptable approach, or is there a better approach. I did not want to use GLM given the nature of the sample.
2. Would it be reasonable to run an additional median regression defining one of the other groups as a reference in order to get a comparison between A and B. Or again is there a better approach for a pairwise comparison which adjusts for age, sex, and post-mortem delay?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! If you were doing it for means (square loss) instead of medians (absolute loss), what would you do?